# Trying to compare Image Button Drawable Image that contained with Drawable that in Resources

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to code Sign In System and I am trying to make skip button in Android app. that if all information in the page still empty then skip button still Enabled. When any info entered skip button Disabled.

The problem that i cant compare between default drawable that I determine for That Image Button and the user image that he entered to enable Skip Button or disabled it.

```
        boolean b5 = (R.drawable.ic_launcher_background == signUpStepTwoPersonalImgImageButton.getTag());
```

The Massage AndroidStudio to me **comparison between Object and primitive is illegal**

Comment: `the user image that he entered ` -> means you're dealing with `onActivityReslt()`, here, you can have a boolean set to true--implying the user has entered an image. Using this boolean, you can design the flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not able to understand your question completely. But it looks like you want to compare two images, one is saved in your drawable folder and other will uploaded by user. If that the case, you can look into Bitmap sameAs method.

[SameAs Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap#sameAs%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29)

**Note:** Bitmap sameAs method is applicable for >=API 12